# Understanding how the omer was sifted

Tags: rashi, talmud-bavli, maseches-menachos, mincha-meal-offering

*M'nachos* 76 *amud* 2, describes how flour was sifted to yield the good-quality *soles* flour for the *omer* offering that was brought on the second day of *Pesach*. It was sifted thirteen times, the *mishna* says, and the *Bavli* clarifies:

> In a fine [sifter], in a coarse one, in a fine one, in a coarse one. Rabbi *Shim'on* (*ben El'azar*) says: There were thirteen sifters in the Temple, one above another, one above another. The top one collects bran; the bottom one collects *soles*.

There are several different explanations of this on the page of *Vilna shas* itself (besides whatever others may have done with it), and I'll focus on three:

- The commentary attributed to *Rashi* (printed atop the page): *R. Shim'on* disagrees with the first statement (and I'll omit the explanation of the first statement). According to *R. Shim'on*, there are thirteen sifters. The coarsest one catches bran, and the second one sifts out too-fine flour. The resultant coarse flour is then sifted in eleven sifters that are even finer (progressively so) to make sure all the too-fine flour is gone.
- The manuscript-based *Rashi* (printed at the bottom of the page): *R. Shim'on* agrees with and clarifies the first statement. They hold that there are thirteen sifters. The finest one sifts out too-fine flour; then the coarsest one catches bran; then the second-finest sifts out too-fine flour; then the second-coarsest catches bran; then the third-finest… you get the picture. The middlemost sifter yields the good stuff.
- *R. Peretz*'s version of *Rashi*, quoted within the manuscript version of *Rashi* in square brackets: *R. Shim'on* agrees with and clarifies the first statement. They hold that there are thirteen sifters, and the sifting is done as above (the finest, then the coarsest, then the second-finest, etc.). What the coarse ones catch is discarded as bran; but what the fine sifters emit is collected for use in the *mincha*.

I have three questions on the explanations of *R. Shim'on*:

1. According to the commentary attributed to *Rashi*, progressively finer sifters sift out more and more too-fine flour. That doesn't seem like it would work: surely if something didn't pass through a sifter, you'd use a coarser one to sift it out, not a finer one.
2. According to the manuscript-based *Rashi* (not *R. Peretz*'s version), the middlemost sifter yields the correct flour. Is that what's caught by the middlemost sifter, or what it lets out?
3. According to *R. Peretz*'s version of *Rashi*, several sifters (besides the last-used sifter) emit flour that was then used. Was it used for the *omer* or for other offerings?

Comment: If I find the source for this I'll turn it into an answer: I've read that there was an initial coarse grind. Some of the wheat would crumble into fine dust; the bran would be coarse; and what was left could be ground again into more refined flour.